# util error facebook.com android

Tags: android, facebook

I have a strange error when I compile my android project. The error appears in Util.java, a class that is in facebook package of my project. The error is:

error: incompatible types
required: Response
found: String

The error is reported in method parseJson(Response response) of Util class,but this method is never called by my project! Why this error? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Util is depreciated so you should not be using it at all. Download the latest source code too!

Comment: It's already the last version. If you see the last SDK it contains the Util class and the parseJson() method...